# Introducing the GD.SE Strike Force!

Tags: discussion

The 'GD Strike Force' (because it sounds pretty cool) have been doing some interesting cross-pacific brainstorming sessions to see how we can finally turn GD.SE into a healthy release!

So we've come up and started working on some projects (with stylish names for them too), that include:

- **Tag Wiki Initiative** (giving definitions to all front page tags)
- **Lonely Tags Project** (improving tagging for older questions)
- **Frankenchat** or how to keep our little online space alive
- **SO Tag Appropriation** (a list of tags to SO keep an eye on for possible migration requests).

And more...

So, if you would like to join the Strike Team, first thing you can do is [visit the Trello board here](https://trello.com/board/gd-se-strike-force/519ec900d51109877d002024). You can sign up there, leave a comment here, or contact John or Yisela, and we will send you an invitation so you can edit cards.

If you are not interested in participating actively, you can still act as an undercover and clean tags, edit questions and keep the chat alive :)

Answer (score 2):

may I suggest possibly allowing a critique option?  I say that because I see many coding posts on how I can better perform "this script".  It would be:

1. A good learning experience
2. Teach how to take criticism
3. Add another option and to me more life to GD because it seems we cover much of the technical side and not the creative side.
4. Most questions we get asked are beginner questions already.

Just a thought and to me a good way to integrate with my peers.